# Retrieving mulitple messages from a single rabbit MQ queue using java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

I know we can get a single message from the queue using `basic.get()`. But I'm not able to retrieve all the messages (maybe 10) in the queue using that. I got some answers to use `basic.consume()` but not sure how to use it and fetch the messages in queue. can some one help me.

I am new to rabbit mq.

Comment: Please see the response from @Gabriele! Don't use `basic.get`! You should also read about QoS / Prefetch.

Comment: @LukeBakken- there is nothing wrong with using `basic.get`- it is a pull vs push approach. Many people find a pull approach to match up better with their consuming logic.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to retrive messages is to use `basic.consume()`, there are several examples around.

But I suggest to start from here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

This is the code to consume messages using `basic.consume`:

```
    String QUEUE_NAME= "hello"
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
                             AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
      throws IOException {
    String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
  }
};
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
```